# Azure Active Directory Group Delta API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azureportal, delta

I am using the Azure Active Directory Group API for my tenant to list all the groups. I am using GET **DELTA**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$select=resourceBehaviorOptions,groupTypes,membershipRuleProcessingState,mail,visibility,displayName,mailEnabled,createdDateTime,creationOptions,proxyAddresses,securityIdentifier,resourceProvisioningOptions,id,securityEnabled,mailNickname,members

According to the documentation, this call when I make for the first time should give me all the meta-data related to groups and in the end it should give me a "**delta-link**". This delta link when called later would just give the changes that have been made in the meta-data of group since then.

However during the first call only when I should be getting all the meta-data, I am getting resources with annotations @**removed**. According to my understanding I should get the changes only when I call the delta link and not for the first time when I am getting all the data

I wanted to know if this is a feature (Microsoft returns @removed for groups which were removed let's day 10 days ago). Or this is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this in my Lab and its same for me as well while making a call `GET /groups/delta` it provides me with a nextlink and it also provides the users I had removed few days back from a group as well.

So, the remove made earlier are shown first response and in nextlink which is expected **as per the Microsoft documentation : The @removed object can be returned in the initial delta query response and in tracked (deltaLink) responses** and the new changes that were made after the delta call can be tracked in the delta link response.

**Reference:** [Use delta query to track changes in Microsoft Graph data - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#resource-representation-in-the-delta-query-response)

[group: delta - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response)

**Sample testing using Graph explorer:**

1. Setting up the delta call, In response I get all the details of my
   Groups and a nextlink for more details, until finally I get the
   deltalink.

[image]

2. I have created a user into the group after initial response.

[image]

3. In deltalink response , I get the detail of the user added.

[image]